# Problem with password working with a remote git server

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a git folder in a remote server, to which I can access without a problem doing the following from my local PC:

```
ssh -i /path-to-ssh-keys-folder/id_rsa_cm {user}@{remote-ip}
```

Also, I have that git folder cloned in my local PC. Until a few days ago I can work with git without using any password. In fact, I have created any password at any time. I want to clarify that it has nothing to do with GitHub.

But now, every time I try to do something with git it requieres me a password, like this:

```
{user}@{remote-ip}'s password:
```

But nothing works.

Should I do something with the public or private ssh key?

Answer (score 0):

> every time I try to do something with git it requieres me a password

You will need to be more specific regarding the exact commands which are triggerring a prompt: those should be:

- `git ls-remote`
- `git clone`
- `git pull`
- `git fetch`
- `git push`

Beside those, any other command should be local only (`git add`, `git commit`, ...) and should not require any credential.

If they do, maybe you have a git alias or a git wrapping script.

The [OP Á. Garzón](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10743303/%C3%81-garz%C3%B3n) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470082/problem-with-password-working-with-a-remote-git-server/68480354?noredirect=1#comment121026996_68480354):

> I could solve it cloning again with the alias of my ssh key, although I don't know why this way worked.

Probably because of `~/.ssh/config`, which defines the right key to use for the remote repository.

Comment: Hi VonC. You are right, the problem appeared with commands related with the remote server, as clone, fetch or pull. Finally, I could solve it cloning again with the alias of my ssh key, although I don't know why this way worked.

Comment: @Á.Garzón Good to hear. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.